# What does inconsistent test results mean?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm doing some research on CNN for text classification using tensorflow. When I run my model I get a very high training accuracy (arround 100%). However, on test split I get an inconsistent accuracy results (sometimes 11% and sometimes 90%).

Moreover, I noticed also that the loss in training is decreasing until it reaches small numbers like 0.000499564048368, while in testing it is not and sometimes it gets high values like 70. What does this mean? Any ideas?

Comment: by "inconsistent results" you mean for **some splits** you get 10% and for some splits you get 90%?

Comment: No. I mean during training steps. for example: in step 2000 I get 92%. However, in step 3000 I get 11%.

Comment: How many data points are in your test data?

Comment: Around 8000 but the dataset is not balanced. It contains 7000 negative samples and 1000 positive samples.

Comment: is your batch **randomized**? Or you always traverse training data in the same order? And 11% is simply when you are pushing batches containing mostly positive samples?

Comment: yes they are randomized

Answer (score 1):

If you get very high training accuracy and bad testing accuracy, you are almost definitely overfitting. To get a better picture of what your models real accuracy is, use cross-validation.

Cross validation splits the dataset into a training and validation set, and does this multiple times, slightly changing the training and validation data each time. This is beneficial because it can prevent scenarios where you train your model on one label, and it can't accurately identify another one. For example, picture a training set like this:

```
Feature1, Feature2, Label
   x          y       0
   a          y       0
   b          c       1
```

If we train the model only on the first two datapoints, it will not be able to identify the third datapoint because it is not built generally.

Comment: But the model can achieve high results (92%) in some steps while it gets (11%) in other steps of the testing process.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by steps? Describe the steps. How are you testing the data?

Comment: In tensorflow, you define a number of steps, such as: 8000. In each step, you send a batch of data to the model and then you can evaluate your model after a certain number (each 100 steps for example). https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/mechanics